# Git illogical commit when changing a refactored version of a directory to original

Tags: git

I had a directory src and a directory src_ref that that contained the contents of src but refactored in severals ways. I renamed src_ref to src and src to src_dep and commited after `git add -A`. What git did makes no sense and I do not understand the internals of git to make sense of it. Here is the deterministic behavior that occurs:

```
In the diff log it makes no mention of the directory src_dep.
The files now in src form src_ref are commited as new files.
```

After attempting to switch to a different branch it says:

```
fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: File exists
```

However it partially checks out the branch. Executing the command again of course specifies that a subset of files have changed in the working directory.

Commiting these changes (cause by the partial checkout of the branch) still results in the `fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: File exists` when attempting to recheckout out the other branch.

The relevant part with regards to the fact that the commit did not appear to have any reference to src_dep: doing `git reset --hard HEAD~` to the commit, still recreates the src_dep directory although it does not appear to be present in the diff as specified above.

It would appear that this type of corruption is catastrophic to the use of git (in my case as I have no interest in dealing with tech that corrupts data and would thus cease using it entirely) as it appears that the only reasonable way to fix this would be recreate the git repository losing all of the branching or:

```
Save the changes from the commit that caused the fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: File exists
git reset --hard HEAD~
Apply the changes manually again and pick a different way to change src_ref to src
```

The questions are:

1. The logically correct diff would be the movement of files from src_ref to src and the movement of files from src to src_dep. This certainly does not happen with a large number of files in src being created, with some being moved from src_ref to src and no reference to src_dep in the diff at all. Is it possible for git to implement the correct logic perhaps with some diff settings?
2. Is this documented and expected behavior with regards to changing a directory containing slightly modified files to a directory already commited? Ie, I want to be able to have a src_ref that gets changed to src, with the priority to have repository versioning that doesn't break/corrupt (ie it would be nice to have logically correct movement but I would settle to just having the repository not corrupt).
3. What is the pattern of operation to resolve this as I do intend to have such duplicated refactored directories that eventually need to be commited as the the new src?

Comment: are you on linux? how big is your repo? are the files stored on local storage? what tool do you use (if not command line)? is your machine seriously underpowered?

Comment: The repo is 37mb with 19.9mb being the .git folder at this time including the corrupted commit. The files are stored in a FAT32 truecrypt volume which I have not had any file system issues with. I commmited this with git 1.7.9 on cygwin. My machine is Windows x86 with 3gb RAM (max allowed) on an Intel P8700 2.53GHZ. I viewed the diff with QGit but that is not really relevant I don't think.

Comment: To clarify what my question is (OP edited): Is this documented and expected behavior with regards to changing a directory containing slightly modified files to a directory already commited? What is the pattern of operation to resolve this as I do intend to have such duplicated refactored directories that eventually need to be commited as the the new src.

Comment: This issue is very disheartening because I believe I would have difficulty creating a test example to recreate the error and thus would be unable to submit a bug report. I have no understanding of what would cause this, even whether the lack of diff of src_dep is relevant or not.

Comment: if you have a folder `src` and move this `src -> src.old` and introduce a new folder `src`, say via doing a rename `src.new -> src` git will not understand this. it will see a lot of newly added files in `src.old` a lot of changed files in `src` and a lot of deleted files in `src.new`. depending on the situation but nothing that one can rely on it will consider some addition/deletion pairs as renames, but no all and not in a manner that makes sense so a human. an approach that would go well with git in this case would be different `branches`for `src`,`src.new`,`src.stable` - character limit :(

Comment: to continue my last post: you should read about branches and decide if they can be useful in your situation. one remark about the general situation: git is a die-hard linux/unix application (it was created by the creator of linux). a lot of things are highly optimized and "done right" (from the linux point of view). these optimizations and assumptions are often wrong on windows and cause problems there (line endings, filesystem case sensitivity, permission bits, symlinks, availability of ssh, ...). the situation is improving on windows, but everything but a default setup is calling for trouble

Comment: Not related to the question of corruption, but... Git does not detect moves/copies by default - you will probably get a more reasonable diff if you add `-M` (or `-C` to detect copies). You can globally enable rename/copy detection by setting `diff.renames` to `true`/`copy`.

Comment: Well, I confirmed that the commit properly saved the changes (I misstated that it did not reference src_dep, it did. The pattern to the diff was as you specified). I did ```git reset HEAD~``` and changed the naming scheme back to the way it was removing the change of renaming src_ref to src and src to src_dep. I recommited, however, the nmap error persists and the associated partial checkout. There are no files of a large size in this repository. Please specify if possible all possible causes of the nmap error. Can the error occur because the corruption persists despite the reset?

Comment: Okay, I attempted to copy the repository and got a ```cannot copy the file is corrupted or unreadable``` error on an object file. I actually received an error from qgit referencing the same hash. This is extremely troubling as to the integrity of git. Please specify if there is a way to recover the repository. Perhaps the object files are not the sole data structure of the repo.

Comment: Well, I replaced the ```.git``` with a back up and recommited without the src_ref to src change. It did not cause any corruption. I guess I'll check what happens with said change.

Comment: The commit causes corruption deterministically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change one folder at a time commiting for each change. src->src_dep commit and then src_ref->src